# where does the repeater get it data bound items?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a look at databinding for the first time.  I understand that the databound elements are put in the aspx file between <%# and %>.  I also understand that a Repeater class is used. Like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="gvEvents" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="eventLogItem">
            <h1><%# Eval("Event")%></h1>
            <time><%# Eval("Timestamp")%></time><small><%# Eval("User")%></small>
            <span class="nav">mouseover to view comments</span>
            <textarea disabled="disabled"><%# Eval("Comments") %></textarea>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater> `
```

But where would the aspx code get "Event", "Timestamp" and "User" and "Comments"?  There does not seem to be something clear in the code-behind file.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In your code behind you would set the `DataSource` property of the repeater to some collection of object in which each of those objects contains a property named `Event`, `Timestamp`, `User`, and `Comments`.  If you don't assign a data source, then there won't be anything for the repeater to display.  If any of the bound items is missing one of those properties, you'll get an error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the code behind for gvEvents.DataSource = ... that is how the database is called for the databinding of the repeater class